# CSS Resize multiple images so that they have a custom width, but same aspect ratio

Tags: css

If I have multiple images with different aspect ratios, but want them all to be resized such that the widths are equal, but the height is changed so that original aspect ratio is maintained, I can do this with JS and math but is there a short css solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply set the `width` using CSS and not set the `height` and the height will be adjusted for you while maintaining the aspect ratio.

```css
img { width: 100px }
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5PGK.jpg">
```

But note the if you worry that the height may turn out to be exceedingly large, you can also use [`max-height`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh) to limit it.  But doing so may distort the image:

```css
img { width: 100px; max-height: 160px }
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5PGK.jpg">
```

One solution is just to set a `max-width` and `max-height` on the image:

```css
img { max-width: 100px; max-height: 120px }
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5PGK.jpg">
```

and the image will be contained in the box with the proper aspect ratio.

There are also techniques such as to create a viewing box of a fixed size, and set `overflow: hidden` to limit the display area to the size of the box, while setting a fixed width for the image:

```css
.image-box { width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden }
.image-box img { width: 100px }
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5PGK.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's why [object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) property comes 
it really helpful in your case and it usually used with [Object-position](https://codeburst.io/object-fit-and-object-position-super-css-55c325ed3006)